# Gentics Mesh Schema can't be found after just creating it

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, gentics-mesh

I'm able to create a new schema using the MeshRestClient, and get a successful response back.

Although, just after that, I try to create a node using the schema and I get an exception about missing the referenced schema.

Log output from creating a schema -

```
12:30:13.177 [] INFO  [vert.x-worker-thread-9] [JULLogDelegate.java:167] - 127.0.0.1 - POST /api/v1/schemas/f0ee56b03d514a5fae56b03d519a5f04 HTTP/1.1 201 835 - 20 ms
12:30:13.179 [] INFO  [main] [MeshService.java:81] - created schema - uuid: f0ee56b03d514a5fae56b03d519a5f04, name: form_definition
```

Then when creating a new node using that schema reference -

```
Caused by: com.gentics.mesh.rest.client.MeshRestClientMessageException: Error:404 in POST /api/v1/demo/nodes : Not Found Info: Object with uuid "f0ee56b03d514a5fae56b03d519a5f04" could not be found.
```

I tried setting the schema name and the schema reference in the NodeCreateRequest, but both complain.

```
    public MeshRequest<NodeResponse> saveFormDefinition(Map<String, Object> form) {
        NodeCreateRequest nodeCreateRequest = new NodeCreateRequest()
                .setSchema(formDefinitionSchema.toReference())
                .setLanguage("en")
                .setParentNodeUuid(formsFolderNode);
        String formName = (String)form.get("name");
        nodeCreateRequest.getFields().putString("name", formName);
        return this.client.createNode(this.meshProjectName, nodeCreateRequest);
    }
```

Is there a time period I need to wait before it's available?
Or any other thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I never subscribed to the assignSchemaToProject request -

```java
client.assignSchemaToProject(meshProjectName, response.getUuid())
```

So after I subscribed, the request was executed and now available for the CreateNodeRequest.

```java
client.assignSchemaToProject(meshProjectName, response.getUuid()).blockingGet();
```